# My wp-admin stops working suddenly

Tags: wp-admin

wp-admin stopped working suddenly.

I have checked the .htaccess file as well as wp config. However still it's not working.

Site is working correctly but wp-admin page re-directs to to auth=1. Don't know what happened. I tried to backup the .htaccess file but still don't works.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to see the login screen? When exactly do you get redirected?

Try to go to http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php enter your user and password, and see if it works. If it works, the issue could be related to a plug-in.